# Cannot run dotnet core 2.1 project on Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-2.1

I have just created a web application with the latest .Net Core Preview sdks. I am trying to run it on Docker for Windows however the project does not build.
The error I am receiving is:

Error The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set.

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  testdocker:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}testdocker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TestDocker\Dockerfile
```

Its override is:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  testdocker:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80      
    ports:
      - "62412:80"
      - "44394:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Can someone direct me some direction please? I am new to Docker and I thought the VS template could just build after installing docker for winodw.
I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49795793/cannot-run-dot-net-core-preview-project-on-docker),but I don't understand the solution and where to add the export.

Further information:
The error points me to this file:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets 363

Comment: What do you see in the output window? I had multiple errors but it always ended with the "Error The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set." error message. Checking output window gave me more info about the actual problem.

Comment: Error  The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Building testdocker
Impossible to perform platform-targeted builds for API version < 1.35.

For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting docker-compose C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets 363

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue in Docker.

See https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5969 and https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/103

Comment: I don't think its the same problem. I have tried to edited the `build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TestDocker/Dockerfile` to `build:
      context: ./TestDocker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile` . Same error persist. `Error The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. Building testdocker Impossible to perform platform-targeted builds for API version < 1.35. docker-compose C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets 363 `

Answer (score 0):

what version of docker-compose do you have?

`docker-compose version`

Are you running Docker Edge channel or Docker Stable channel? If you are running edge you probably have docker-compose 1.21.2 which causes this issue, I had same error, switched to Docker Stable channel and docker-compose 1.21.1 and it works.

Comment: I am new to docker and I can only see version 3.4 on my docker-compose.yml and override file

Comment: Just found the version when clicked about.It is 1.21.2 and I am using docker edge. I am not sure how to switch it, does that mean I have to remove docker and install an early release?

Comment: I just installed 1.21.2 version. I am get another error now. Volume sharing is not enabled. Enable volume sharing in the Docker CE for Windows Settings.

Comment: A firewall is blocking file Sharing between Windows and the containers. See documentation for more info. Found [this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203488/settings-to-windows-firewall-to-allow-docker-for-windows-to-share-drive/43904051#43904051)]. this powershell gives error code  HRESULT 0x80041013,Set-NetConnectionProfile